PHP Error InvalidArgumentException: "user_id" is an invalid render array key. Site is down after updating

Value should be an array but got a string. in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php

This is a Drupal 10.3.10 site on PHP 8.2.26. I am not sure what the problem is here since I have another site I updated which does not show that error.
Do you have any idea?

What got updated? If you updated multiple modules at once, roll back the update and then start updating the modules one at a time to see what is causing the exception.

Another way to find the module causing the error is to enable full error messages and look further down the stack trace until you find the module machine name. If you can't reach the admin UI anymore because of the error, put this line in settings.php: $config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose'; and reload the page.

Thanks guys, but still on the struggle bus.

The error is caused by a render array key containing a string but not having a #:
'user_id' => '123',

It should be
'#user_id' => '123',

or it should contain a renderable sub-array:
'user_id' => ['#markup' => '123'],

'user_id' is used only about 100 times in Drupal core and only in tests. So it could be possible to find the error by comparing the results of a grep search of a working and a non-working site:
grep -r "'user_id'"

returns about 100 results and excluding tests
grep -r "'user_id'" | grep -v tests

no results on Drupal core alone. If this gets results you should be able to locate the error.
